# Vue 3 component didn't showing up in my laravel 10 blade

Tags: vue-component, laravel-blade, laravel-10

I have problem about showing vue component in blade. I tried using adding x syntax like <x-example-component></x-example-component>, but it give me error message 'Unable to locate a class or view for component [example-component].'. If I delete x syntax, the component didn't show up properly.

my **app.js** file

```
import './bootstrap';
window.Vue = require('vue').default;


Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'example-component': require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'),
    }
});
```

blade.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" content="text/html"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Laravel Vue</title>

      <!-- Fonts Google -->
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bungee+Shade&family=Urbanist:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

      <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d03dc02237.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style>
        body{
            font-family: 'Urbanist', sans-serif;
        }
        .nama-app{
            font-family: 'Bungee Shade', cursive;
        }
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <h1 class="nama-app"> Halo </h1>
            <example-component></example-component>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**ExampleComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name:'example-component',
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "watch": "vite build --watch"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.8.0",
        "sass": "^1.56.1",
        "vite": "^4.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.37"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue-router": "^4.2.5"
    }
}
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            output: 'public',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});
```

i tried using npm run dev or npm run watch and inspect but the <example-component></example-component> didn't showed anything. How to solve it? Thank you

Comment: `new Vue({` is Vue 2 syntax, so sounds like you're mixing versions.